# Grab Custom Arguments from SendGrid Event Webhook PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to pull custom arguments when I send email through SendGrid and pull them into my database when they are saved through Event Notification.

I have event notification setup so that after SendGrid processes email, it saves it into my DB, I just can't figure out how to pull the custom arguments I'm sending.

I send the argument like this:

```
$mail->addCustomArg("campaign", "welcome69");
```

And then am running into issues trying to receive it (after SendGrid posts it)

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$events = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($events as $event) {
$sg_event_id = $event['sg_event_id'];
$unique_args = $event['unique_args'];
}
```

In the bottom code snipet, the variable $unique_args works, the second one does not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What [Sendgrid `POSTs` to your hook is a JSON Object](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html). You can retrieve `unique_args` directly by writing something like

```
$unique_args = $events['unique_args']; // this is an associative array.
```

You can walkthrough the associative array using a foreach loop this way:

```
foreach($unique_args as $field => $value) {
}
```